# MongoDB Connection Pattern using Monger

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

I am new to clojure.

Are there any idioms/patterns around connecting to mongodb through monger?

Do I have to connect and disconnect using

```
(monger.core/connect) & (monger.core/disconnect conn)
```

respectively. each time ?

Is there a way I can reuse a connection from a connection pool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

monger uses MongoClient, which does connection pooling. After you `connect`, you can keep working with that pool until you're done, and then `disconnect`. See the [monger documentation](http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/connecting.html#supported_connection_options) for supported connection options (e.g. maximum number of connections in the pool, default 10).

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. This is a web application. When you say keep working with that pool until you are done, would each request have to connect and disconnect?

Comment: No, you want to call connect before you launch the app (jetty, I assume). Query the db from your routes, no need to connect every time.

Comment: How do I get back the connection in subsequent requests, since the (monger.collection/insert), (monger.collection/find-one-as-map) functions seem to require a db as a parameter and the (monger.core/get-db) function requires a connection as a parameter?

Comment: When you connect, put the connection in an atom so you can see it from all subsequent calling threads.

Comment: very helpful comments and answer, thanks everyone for being so friendly and respectful and insightful ^_^

Comment: I realise this is an old thread but it seems still relevant. I have one further question: do I need to worry about concurrency or can I just share the same connection object among all my threads and let the connection pool worry about allocating physical connections?

Answer (score 2):

We just need example code, right? The documentation only talks about creating locally bound connections through `let`, so this will get you started:

```
(ns pipegen.core
    (:require [monger.core :as mg]
              [monger.collection :as mc]))

(def conn (atom (mg/connect-via-uri mongo-uri)))
(mc/insert (:db @conn) "collectionname" {:name "methuzula" :age 123})
```

It wasn't clear to me, from documentation, the return type of `mg/connect-via-uri`, so I'll mention briefly in case it helps someone:

```
{:conn #object[com.mongodb.MongoClient]
 :db   #object[com.mongodb.DB]}
```

If you save that to a `def`, you can reuse it as needed.

---

Side Notes, less related to your question, but will probably help you:

This may not be the best design pattern for connecting to dbs. Here are some design patterns for dependency injection I enjoyed reading through, it gives some better ideas of passing around the mongo  connection context, the Reader Monad seems particularly cool, I'll have to try it out myself! http://software-ninja-ninja.blogspot.co.il/2014/04/5-faces-of-dependency-injection-in.html

Also, `clojurians` on `slack` is a friendly community I didn't find out until after many a headache with clojure, check em out! https://clojurians.slack.com/

Comment: Any reason to put the connection in an `atom` in stead of simply putting directly in the `var`?